# Parse urls python

Tags: python, pandas, url, beautifulsoup

So im using this code to get a list of URLs, the thing is that i need a column with the URLS and another one with the tags or the text

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

getpage= requests.get

getpage_soup= BeautifulSoup(getpage.text, 'html.parser')

all_links= getpage_soup.findAll('a')

for link in all_links:
    print (link)
```

What i'm expecting is a dataframe similar to this

```
pd.DataFrame({'link': 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t1hLPvUkfCde1wglfjAh--r8NpLONbRf/view?usp=sharing', 'tag': 'Estatal 2020'})
```

Comment: Could you add a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @MrNobody33 sorry, fixed

Comment: Please, read the link I attached. You should add an expected output from a given example input and what have you tried so far

Comment: fixed, try number 2. @MrNobody33

Comment: That's cleaner! I just added an answer @AngelSerrano. Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Using your first example of what you need, this may can help you:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.gob.mx/sesnsp/acciones-y-programas/incidencia-delictiva-del-fuero-comun-nueva-metodologia?state=published"
data = []
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'article-body'}) # get div "article-body"
for ul in div.findAll('ul'): # get all 'ul' tags inside div "article-body"
    for li in ul.findAll('li'): # get all 'li' inside 'ul'
        for link in li.findAll('a', href=True): # get 'a' inside li
            data.append([link['href'], link.text]) # link['href'] = url | link.text = "Estatal 2020"

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['link', 'tag'])
print(dataframe)
```

```
[OUTPUT]
                                                 link                  tag
0   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t1hLPvUkfCde1...         Estatal 2020
1   https://drive.google.com/open?id=17MnLmvY_YW5Z...         Estatal 2019
2   https://drive.google.com/open?id=11DcfF4Pvp_21...         Estatal 2018
3   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Y0aqq6w2EQij...         Estatal 2017

[/OUTPUT]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
getpage= requests.get('https://www.gob.mx/sesnsp/acciones-y-programas/incidencia-delictiva-del-fuero-comun-nueva-metodologia?state=published')

getpage_soup= BeautifulSoup(getpage.text, 'html.parser')

all_links= getpage_soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("(^http://)|(^https://)")})   #get all the urls with protocols http or https

data=[]
for link in all_links:
    if link.text.strip()=='':   #if the link doesn't have text, add the id
        data.append([link['href'], link.get('id')])
    else:
        data.append([link['href'], link.text.strip()])   #add the text without trailing and leading whitespaces

df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['link', 'tag'])   #create the dataframe
print(df)
```

Output:

```
df
                                                 link                                                tag
0                         https://coronavirus.gob.mx/        Información importante Coronavirus COVID-19
1                  https://www.gob.mx/busqueda?utf8=✓                                           botbusca
2   https://www.gob.mx/sesnsp/acciones-y-programas...                                      Transparencia
3   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t1hLPvUkfCde1...                                       Estatal 2020
4   https://drive.google.com/open?id=17MnLmvY_YW5Z...                                       Estatal 2019
5   https://drive.google.com/open?id=11DcfF4Pvp_21...                                       Estatal 2018
6   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Y0aqq6w2EQij...                                       Estatal 2017
7   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mgFsF3rdoYLE...                                       Estatal 2016
8   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RQhk58-fHNPr...                                       Estatal 2015
9   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WIzrjJTF24DCX...                                       Estatal 2020
10  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QtjDM7pczeST...                                       Estatal 2019
11  https://drive.google.com/open?id=15l9hl4eUmFCM...                                       Estatal 2018
12  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FO4W0HK8cdPk...                                       Estatal 2017
13  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tDEjJ1XLdFP8...                                       Estatal 2016
14  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lCeFrMi_D-Gr...                                       Estatal 2015
15  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q8AdhfxpLdF_l...                                Estatal 2015 - 2020
16  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jopZOChRppi6Q...                                          Mayo 2020
17  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CvHXHC48SYWT...                                       Febrero 2020
18  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QxUe0HwLNNZH...                                         Enero 2020
19  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KZzHGdTlH5ya...                                     Diciembre 2019
20  https://drive.google.com/open?id=119VQ5-1JPnWZ...                                     Noviembre 2019
21  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CbNV3sTkSn3t...                                       Octubre 2019
22  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gpMM2pi6Ta-r...                                    Septiembre 2019
23  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dHUhpr-DbOPx...                                        Agosto 2019
24  https://drive.google.com/open?id=18CQlwY07tTaa...                                         Julio 2019
25  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EnhF4IOFxqLr...                                         Junio 2019
26  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wrTEwP5Q3xwZ...                                          Mayo 2019
27  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZuY20S-5Gi8l...                                         Abril 2019
28  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1P2Xvs7kLLclg...                                         Marzo 2019
29  https://drive.google.com/open?id=16FWEKbbJ83KL...                                       Febrero 2019
30  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mIw1XKJBY8ZV...                                         Enero 2019
31  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iTGBC1Ge4UWP...                                     Diciembre 2018
32  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Kmtir0rhQLf7...                                     Noviembre 2018
33  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1r7SHNfKVXGfe...                                       Octubre 2018
34  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IKpGJbJuNQKW...                                    Septiembre 2018
35  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1spqdNT0T0pen...                                        Agosto 2018
36  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1k07ZSk2c4irk...                                         Julio 2018
37  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HX4SlChjRbMm...                                         Junio 2018
38  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ErSyO9-rfHi3...                                          Mayo 2018
39  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cK5lR33-mA6-...                                         Abril 2018
40  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MaqJaSfq2KxB...                                         Marzo 2018
41  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GaoDPWud-2Iy...                                       Febrero 2018
42  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OXITYyRrUBwj...                                         Enero 2018
43  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KwjGdNYez72_z...                                Estatal 2015 - 2020
44  https://drive.google.com/file/d/14fDk5sBry1DOo...                              Municipal 2015 - 2020
45  https://www.gob.mx/sesnsp/acciones-y-programas...  Regresar al menú principal de Incidencia Delic...
46  https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=h...                                          Compartir
47                        http://www.participa.gob.mx                                          Participa
48                              https://datos.gob.mx/                                              Datos
49                   https://www.gob.mx/publicaciones                            Publicaciones Oficiales
50  https://www.infomex.org.mx/gobiernofederal/hom...                                    Sistema Infomex
51                             http://www.inai.org.mx                                               INAI
52                    http://www.ordenjuridico.gob.mx                                     Marco Jurídico
53                 https://www.facebook.com/gobmexico                                           Facebook
54                     https://twitter.com/GobiernoMX                                            Twitter
```

And if you only want the ones that start with `"Estatal"`, you can add this to the code above:

```
import numpy as np
mask=np.where(df.tag.str.startswith('Estatal'), True, False)
print(df[mask])
```

Output:

```
                                                 link                  tag
3   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t1hLPvUkfCde1...         Estatal 2020
4   https://drive.google.com/open?id=17MnLmvY_YW5Z...         Estatal 2019
5   https://drive.google.com/open?id=11DcfF4Pvp_21...         Estatal 2018
6   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Y0aqq6w2EQij...         Estatal 2017
7   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mgFsF3rdoYLE...         Estatal 2016
8   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RQhk58-fHNPr...         Estatal 2015
9   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WIzrjJTF24DCX...         Estatal 2020
10  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QtjDM7pczeST...         Estatal 2019
11  https://drive.google.com/open?id=15l9hl4eUmFCM...         Estatal 2018
12  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FO4W0HK8cdPk...         Estatal 2017
13  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tDEjJ1XLdFP8...         Estatal 2016
14  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lCeFrMi_D-Gr...         Estatal 2015
15  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q8AdhfxpLdF_l...  Estatal 2015 - 2020
43  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KwjGdNYez72_z...  Estatal 2015 - 2020
```